# Masking part of a UIView

Tags: ios4, uikit, core-animation

I am animating a UIView (think popup menu) and I would like to mask part of a UIView as the menu bar is transparent and the UIView is sliding down from behind the menu bar.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want an animation that looks like this:

```
1. /--\      2. /--\     3. /--\
                |--|        |--|
                            \--/
```

If that's what you mean, then you could take a look at how WipeView is implemented (look at [WipeView.h](https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty/blob/master/WipeView.h) and [WipeView.m](https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty/blob/master/WipeView.m)).  This does the opposite animation (from 3->1), but I think you can easily modify the code to achieve the effect you want.  It uses the `contentsRect` property of `CALayer`.

Here's a [blog post explaining the WipeView class](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=130).